# How can i disable Related Post tab on product page magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, tabs, product-page, related-products

I want detail tab to active at first also related product tab to be hidden or disable.
[image: magento 2.3 product page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the block name of "Related Posts" by enabling `Template Path Hints` and `Block Path Hints` in `Store->Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Debug`. Set `Template Path Hints` and `Add Block Names to Hints` to yes. Refresh the cache and find for the block name in Product Detailed Page near to Related Posts tab.

Look for the block name in `catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` and remove it.

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks Mate problem solved.
<referenceBlock name="related.post.tab" remove="true"></referenceBlock>